# php session variable problem when unset

Tags: php, session-variables, unset

i have made a function to set a session variable $_SESSION['flash'] in order to store a message between page

```
function setFlash($string,$type="info") {

    switch ($type) {
        case "warning":
            $_SESSION['flashtype'] = "warning";
            break;
        case "error":
            $_SESSION['flashtype'] = "error";
            break;
        case "info":
            $_SESSION['flashtype'] = "info";
            break;
        default:
            $_SESSION['flashtype'] = "info";
            break;
    }
    $_SESSION['flash'] = $string;   
}
```

and a function to print this message

```
function printFlash() {
      echo $_SESSION['flash'];
      unset($_SESSION['flash']);

}
```

i call this function at the top of every page (naturally after session_start)

the problem is that it doesn't print nothing, but if I comment "          unset($_SESSION['flash']);" it prints the message in every page.

how can i solve?

---

Solved sorry my fault.

```
my page is something like this

include "func.inc.php"
session start

function editSomething {
  that call setFlash()
  }

include "template.php" (where printFlash() is called)
```

now i put printFlash directly in my page and works..bah strange...what's my mistake?

Comment: Could you show your page flow?

Comment: well...i have some file inclusion for my classes => session_start() => printFlash()....than i have a call to a function that edit a record in the db and if ok => setFlash("Flash Message") => redirect to another page with the same classes inclusion => session_start() => printFlash....the problem is that seems that the unset statement is done before than echo statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every page this is what happened:

- Make a session
- Display flash
- Delete flash
- Create 'flash' with value

You have to move Create before display.

(it's also not very usefull because you do not transmit 'flash' (it's delete right after been created)

Comment: print 'flash' but at the biginning is empty |
unset flash |
set 'flash' |
=> redirect to new page |
print flash |
unset flash |

Comment: So it's seems right, since we had no code to work with, possible errors are: 

Next page haven't session_start(); -- Session is destroy before the next page

Comment: the second page have session_start on the top and if i remove "unset" from the "printFlash" function the second page print the message